# Extract each line and append it to another file from one of the columns

Tags: awk

How is it possible to extract each line from the below file and append the content to a file which is named after 3rd column (e.g. Backbone_3710)?

```
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17889:2254#GNNNNN/11      16      Backbone_3710   13730   1       28M1D61M1D11M   *       0       0       AATAGGGAAAAGCCGGCTATCGGAATCGAACCGATGACCATCGCATTACAAATGCGATGCTCTAACCTCTGAGCTAAGCGGGCCCACATAACAGAAATCT    *       NM:i:5  ms:i:144        AS:i:148        nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:5  s1:i:40 s2:i:59 de:f:0.0490     rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17753:2257#GNNNNN/11      16      Backbone_2546   1217877 23      23S62M1I14M     *       0       0       ATTTGATTGTGCATATTAGTGTGTTTTTTCATTTGTGCATGCATGGCAAGTCATAAAAAATACAAAAGAACTACATAAGCATTTAGGGTTTAATTTCACA    *       NM:i:3  ms:i:118        AS:i:118        nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:3  s1:i:51 s2:i:0  de:f:0.0390     rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17922:2282#ANNNNN/11      16      Backbone_2065   955626  2       16S20M2I7M1D11M3I35M1D6M        *       0       0       GAACGAGAAGAAGATTATTTCAACGTCGAGGCTTGGAAAAACTTTATTTAGGAGCTTCAAATTGATAGGGCAGTCCTACGAGTGGAATAAGAGGACATGT    *       NM:i:9  ms:i:78 AS:i:80 nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:4  s1:i:27 s2:i:0  de:f:0.0723     rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17799:2282#ANNNNN/11      16      Backbone_3859   11630   1       75M1I24M        *       0       0       TCGTGTTCAACACAGTATTCATACGGGAAATTATGATCAAAGAGTTCTTTATCAACCGCCATCTACTTCAGAGATCCCTACGGAAATCTTTTTCAAATAC    *       NM:i:5  ms:i:144        AS:i:144        nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:5  s1:i:47 s2:i:54 de:f:0.0500     rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17876:2290#GNNNNN/11      0       Backbone_1630   114655  2       23S37M40S       *       0       0       ACATGCATAAGGAATCTTTGGCCTAGTCTCAAAAGTCGGTCTAATTCAGAAGTACTAATTCAAGAGATAGAATATGAGGATGAACAAGAGTATGATAAGG    *       NM:i:1  ms:i:64 AS:i:64 nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:3  s1:i:27 s2:i:0  de:f:0.0270     rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17982:2293#GNNNNN/11      4       *       0       0       *       *       0       0       TGATTAAAATAATTGCTCATAAATATAATAGAATTAAAGGAAAAAGGTAAAAGAAAGCATTGAAGAAAAGAAAGAAAGAGCCAAGTTTTATATGCAGTAG    *       rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17833:2296#GNNNNN/11      4       *       0       0       *       *       0       0       TGAGGGTTCCAGATTAAATGCCAATTCAAACTTCCTACTGGGAATCATTGTTCAGGCGAGTTCTGACAACTCTTAGTGGAGAAGGCATTGGTGCCTACCC    *       rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17908:2302#GNNNNN/11      4       *       0       0       *       *       0       0       TAATTTAAATAGTGCATTGGACTTTCAGATTTGGTTCAATATTCAACATGGGTCGACTTCTTATGGATGATTTTAGAAGTGGGTTTGAGGAAGGACCTTG    *       rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17759:2305#ANNNNN/11      16      Backbone_870    367318  10      27M1I34M3D6M1I31M       *       0       0       ACATAGGGCCTCCATTCCCTAGTCGCCTTTTTGGAACATTAGGGCTCCAATCCCAGAGTTGAGTTTAATAGATAGGGCCTCCATTCCCTAGTCGCCTTTT    *       NM:i:13 ms:i:78 AS:i:78 nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:3  s1:i:43 s2:i:42 de:f:0.1089     rl:i:0
HWI-ST945_0069:2:1101:17878:2318#GNNNNN/11      0       Backbone_2304   815440  1       67M1D27M6S      *       0       0       TGGGTTCTTTTATTAAAGACCCTATATGCTTTACTACGTGAGGAATATCCAATGAAAATACCTTCATCCGACTTAGCATCAAATTTACCCAATTAGTCTT    *       NM:i:3  ms:i:160        AS:i:160        nn:i:0  tp:A:P  cm:i:7  s1:i:60 s2:i:71 de:f:0.0316     rl:i:0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want a file named `*`?

Comment: Good point. If it is a star then to ignore the line.

Comment: @user977828: Post the efforts that you made yourself to solve this

Comment: @Inian, you changed the tag from bash to awk, but I don't see any of either language in the question. What did I miss?

Comment: @ghoti: It was tagged with both of them from the OP. I didn't see any relevance for having the `bash` tag in this. So removed that alone!

Comment: @Inian, ah, I mis-read the edit log. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
awk '$3 != "*" { print $0 >> $3; close($3) }' input.txt
```

should work. Note the use of `close()` after every print to avoid running out of file descriptors if there's going to be a bunch of different output files.

Comment: This would be good if there are no duplicate `$3` entries present. If they are present, it would mean opening and closing the file handles for each duplicate entry. The ideal way would be store them and close them all at the end, something like `awk ' $3 !~ "*" { fh[$3]; print $0 >> $3 } END { for (handle in fh) close(handle) } ' file`

Comment: @Inian there's no point to that `END` block because all open files are closed at exit anyways. If OP's data is only going to have up to a few dozen different files written to, leaving out the `close()` is likely fine. Hundreds or thousands? Then you have problems with the limit on open files, and need a way to prune them. This is the easy way.

Comment: They could be 2000 to 10.000 files.